# MongoDB sharding - listing shards

Tags: mongodb, sharding

I'm trying to list the shards using the Java driver with the command:

```
DB adminDB = mongoClient.getDB("admin");
CommandResult res = adminDB.command(new BasicDBObject("listshards ", 1));
```

But the response that I get is:

```
{ "serverUsed" : "/127.0.0.1:25000" , "ok" : 0.0 , "errmsg" : "no such cmd: listshards "}
```

But running "listShards" on the command line seems to work just fine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is `listShards`, case sensitive: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/listShards/#dbcmd.listShards#

You are using `listshards` all lower case

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the internal 'config' DB.  From the command line connect to the mongos process (we are sharded after all).  Show dbs will list 'config' as a DB.

- show dbs
- use config
- show collections

You will see 'shards' as a collection.  Simply find all the documents in this collection.  Each document has two fields: '_id' which is the name of the shard and 'host' which lists the hosts housing the replicas for said shard.